# Simple Nginx proxy pass not working with Laravel Valet installed

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-valet

Quick backstory, I used Laravel Valet to setup a local development environment. I've since containerized the application and would like to just have Nginx proxy the main port 80 traffic to the `localhost:8000` port the docker container is listening at. I've tried to remove (unpark/stop) Valet. I've commented out the lines from the `nginx.conf` that refer to the Valet config files. Nothing seems to work though

Here is my conf:

```
server {
        listen   80;
        server_name  app.trucase.test paylaw.trucase.test;
        location / {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.0:8000;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
```

I can go to `app.trucase.test:8000` and it all works. But without the port, Nginx just isn't proxying the traffic. What am I missing?

Comment: Is `127.0.0.0` configured as your localhost loopback address? Or should it be `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Good catch, it should be `127.0.0.1`. Unfortunately, the behavior has not changed. I get responses from `127.0.0.1:8000`, `app.trucase.test:8000`, but nothing from either `127.0.0.1` or `app.trucase.test`.

Comment: First of all, the `nginx.conf` should have a `http {` section which includes `.conf` files from a certain location like `usr/local/nginx/servers/*.conf`. Create a `app.trucase.test.conf` here and leave the `nginx.conf` alone. Lastly, can you replace the `listen 80` with `listen 127.0.0.1:80; listen [::]:80` and add the following two lines in `location / {`, add `proxy_http_version 1.1;` and a header `proxy_pass_request_headers on;`.

Comment: Results are the same.

```➜  nginx git:(stable) ping app.trucase.test
PING app.trucase.test (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.117 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.202 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.231 ms
^C
➜  nginx git:(stable) wget app.trucase.test
--2023-01-20 12:34:43--  http://app.trucase.test/
Resolving app.trucase.test (app.trucase.test)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to app.trucase.test (app.trucase.test)|127.0.0.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... ^C```

Comment: Current `server` section of `http` in conf:

```server {
 listen 127.0.0.1:80; listen [::]:80;
        server_name  app.trucase.test paylaw.trucase.test;
        location / {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why doesn't markdown work in these comment sections? The formatting is terrible.

Comment: Yea comment section sucks. Ok that proxy should work. Could you add to your answer the following output: `nginx -V` and `nginx -V 2>&1 | tr ' ' '\n'`.

Comment: And have your tried `valet proxy trucase http://127.0.0.1:8000` and see if `http://trucase.test` hits?

Comment: Already removed Valet. I'd love to paste the results of that command but the comment character limit is too small.